# caffe: error with protobuf version

Tags: computer-vision, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, protocol-buffers

I've previously installed caffe and Fast-RCNN, so I should have all the required libraries and dependencies.

I need to install it again for another repository(https://github.com/ronghanghu/natural-language-object-retrieval) that uses Caffe.

When I run

```
make all
```

it gives me the following error:

```
CXX .build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc
In file included from .build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc:5:0:
.build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.h:12:2: error: #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
#error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
^
.build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.h:13:2: error: #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please update
#error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please update
^
.build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.h:14:2: error: #error your headers.
#error your headers.
^
In file included from .build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc:5:0:
.build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.h:26:55: fatal error: google/protobuf/generated_enum_reflection.h: No such file or directory
#include <google/protobuf/generated_enum_reflection.h>

compilation terminated.
make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.o] Error 1
```

I thought maybe protobuf has been updated, and tried

```
protoc --version
```

which returns

```
libprotoc 2.5.0
```

It seems like newer version of protobuf has been released (2.6 or up).

So my question would be:

1) Is there a simple way to update it?

2) If I do update it, will it affect caffe and fast-rcnn that I previously installed, which depends on the older version of protobuf?

Answer (score 4):

I suspect your problem is that you have multiple versions of protobuf in your include path.  It may be picking up the headers from the older version instead of the latest.  I can confirm that latest caffe (git master as of right now) compiles cleanly against the libprotobuf-dev-2.5.0-9ubuntu1 which is in ubuntu 14.04LTS.

Comment: how can I deal with the multiple versions issue?

Comment: was there any solutions to the multiple versions and headers issue?

Comment: I'd be interested in a solution, too. (sorry, I hope this isn't spamming)
How can I link to another version of protobuf located in e.g. /usr/local?

Answer (score 1):

I guess before you get this problem, you have used `protoc` to generate caffe.pb.h`. If you did, my solution maybe be useful to you.

Firstly, you should know how many `protoc` installed in your OS.

For example, in my OS:

```
Prompt> whereis protoc
protoc: /usr/bin/protoc /home/xxx/.conda/envs/python27/bin/protoc/usr/share/man/man1/protoc.1.gz
```

So, there are 2 `protoc` in my OS. You can use `which protoc` and  `protoc --version` in order to find which version `protoc` is used default. In my OS:

```
Prompt> which protoc
/home/xxx/.conda/envs/python27/bin/protoc

Prompt>protoc --version
libprotoc 3.5.1
```

Finally, use another `protoc` to create `caffe.pb.h` again.
let the dir to `caffe/src/caffe/proto`, and execute:

```
/usr/bin/protoc --cpp_out=. caffe.proto
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this on my computer and maybe it can help you. My environment is Ubuntu16.04, and I installed Anaconda(for python2.7) before I install Caffe. It happens that I used conda to install libprotobuf-dev, and this leads to conflict with the caffe's 'sudo apt-get install libprotobuf-dev' command, for 'apt-get' and conda installed different on my computer which can be find by 'locate protobuf', so I remove the Anaconda's version of libprotobuf, and no problem happens again.

```
conda uninstall libprotobuf
```

When you install tensorflow before install Caffe, this problem will also happen, because of the libprotobuf conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by

```
conda uninstall libprotobuf
```

then remove the caffe folder and download a new one

```
git clone https://github.com/BVLC/caffe.git
```

then do

```
make all -j8
```